# How do I calculate below VMs using Azure Pricing Calculator?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, virtual-machine

Please note that I'm new and just started to learn Azure since last two weeks. Well now, I have been given a list VMs with its own specs, for examples:

**VM1**

Type: Active directory (what does that mean?, isn't it different from a VM)

Virtual disk type: fixed

HDD Size: 80GB, Utilization: 30 GB

Guest : Windows Server 2016 Standard

Ram: 8, type: Static

vCPU: 2

**VM2**

Type: Web/DB

Virtual disk type: differencing (what should I do with this information?)

HDD Size: 150GB, Utilization: 9.82 GB

Guest : Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Ram: 4, type: Static

vCPU: 2

I've watched youtube and tutorials on calculating a simple VM but they never considered or mentioned any specifications as above. Thus, I really have no idea how to generate estimation based on these two examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has a great free calculator that you can use to come with an estimate on the following link :

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/
```

Visit the link, then click Virtual Machines, the scroll down to see the form where you can configure different parameters for your VM.

[image]

I believe these are just descriptions for the vms doing/hosting

> Type: Active directory (what does that mean?, isn't it different from a VM) & Type: Web/DB

> I've watched youtube and tutorials on calculating a simple VM but they never considered or mentioned any specifications as above. Thus, I really have no idea how to generate estimation based on these two examples.

yes terms could be confusing at the beginning.
and please note that there are some requirements you need to consider that weren't mentioned such as Region, tier, Up time for your VM..

Here's an example for an estimate for your first VM (please not it's not very accurate) :
https://azure.com/e/f6c712f4825f41c8a76c02b06bbefff7

Comment: got it. thank you so much for your comprehensive explanation! just a couple of questions more to ask, how do you determine the instance? and how should I consider the 'virtual disk type'? does it affect any part of the pricing calculator?

Comment: and as for the second VM, do you think the type should be SQL server, or just OS only?

Comment: it should be OS, then later you can install DB server if requires .. Please mark/vote my answer if it answers your question. good luck

Comment: for disks, see managed disks part and pick the appropriate options if you need to attached a data disk to VMs